# Transfer function reverts

Tags: solidity, address.transfer

I just started learning solidity and i am stuck with address.transfer()
Reverts when using send().
Works fine if i use msg.value but reverts when using uint256 amount to address.transfer().

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
    pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
    
    contract test{
        address payable public owner;
    
        constructor(){
            owner=payable(msg.sender);
        }
    
        function getBalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256){
            return _address.balance;
        }
        function send(address payable _address) payable public {
            require(msg.sender.balance>=20000000000000000000,"Not enough token");
            uint256 amount = 20000000000000000000;
            _address.transfer(amount);
        }
    
    }
```

[image: revert error]

Comment: Did you fund the contract with at least 20 ETH? If not, that's why it reverts.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg if i supply 20 eth through msg.value it works but it doesnt work if i specify the transfer amount like above.

Comment: btw ether is not a "token". maybe you are not sending the correct amount? try require(msg.value == 20000000000000000000, "Sent Ether not enough"); and try to debug the tx to see where it does revert

Comment: @MajdTL it works if i use address.transfer(msg.value) to supply 20 ether. but reverts if i use address.transfer(amount), amount being uint256

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg was right it was because of lack of fund in contract. It seems like if I use address.transfer(msg.value) it transfers the eth from msg.sender but if I use address.transfer(amount) like above it transfers eth from contract itself

Answer (score 1):

From the code it appears the intention is to transfer ether from `msg.sender`.

```
        require(msg.sender.balance>=20000000000000000000,"Not enough token");
        uint256 amount = 20000000000000000000;
        _address.transfer(amount);
```

That's not possible. A contract cannot access the balance of another account. It can only transfers its own balance.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of lack of fund in contract.
It seems like if I use address.transfer(msg.value) it transfers the eth from msg.sender but if I use address.transfer(amount) like above it transfers eth from contract itself

Answer (score 0):

Its due to `require(msg.sender.balance>=20000000000000000000,"Not enough token");`

`function send()` will be reverted if `msg.sender.balance !>= 20 ethers/matic`